# How to handle timestamp in RTMP?

Tags: c++, video, timestamp, rtmp, flv

I'm parse RTMP stream from wireshark capture and write media data to .flv file. I know how to calculate timestamp but a how can i handle timestamp when it overflow?

Comment: Define _"timestamp when it overflow"_... Do you mean when millisecs are too large for integer (4 bytes)? Even FLV has maximum amount (4 bytes) so if this a continous stream after some days you have to use zero again. Maybe have a `long` that keeps larger digits for UI display while adding to it from current detected FLV timestamp. I think that's similar to what @Szatmary is suggesting anyways.

Comment: Yes. I mean that .flv use 24 bit for timestamp and use extended timestamp 32 bit. When 24 bit is set to 0xffffff RTMP use extended timestamp ( 0xffffffXX ). So i solved problen this way : 1) Calculate timestamp from RTMP stream timestamp  += curr_tmpstm; 2) Check if timestamp >= 0xfffff - If timestamp >= 0xfffff then i need to use ext_timestamp = 0xffffffXX - where XX = timestamp - 0xffffff; 3) I after that I write timestamp to .flv file and this works. –

Comment: No worries if it works. I would have done... (2) Check if timestamp >= 0xFFFFFF, `IF` true then write as full 32bit unsigned integer, or `ELSE` write 24bit unsigned (followed by zero byte for "no extend") as usual.

Comment: I write 24 bit timestam (followed by zero byte for "no extend") when extended_timestamp > 0xffffffff.

Comment: You should post your working solution as new Answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So i solved problem this way :
1) Parse RTMP header( read 4 bytes from the beginning of timestamp )  and get timestamp( u_int 32 )  ;

```
if ( ( _timestamp >> 8 ) == 0xffffff ) /* check if extended timestamp is present */
    {
        _timestamp = (_timestamp & 0x000000ff) + 0xffffff;
    }
    else
    {
        _timestamp >>= 8 ;  
    }
```

2) Calculate timestamp for .flv file ( timestamp in .flv file is always 32 bit for example 0x00000100 is simple timestamp and equal 1 and 0xffffff01 is extended timestamp and equal 0xffffff + 0x01 )

```
if ( ( timestamp_calc + _timestamp ) >= 0xffffff )
    {
        unsigned __int8 temp = _timestamp;
        unsigned __int8 * ptr;

        if ( (timestamp_calc + _timestamp) >= 0xffffffff ){ timestamp_calc = _timestamp; }
        else
        {
            timestamp_calc = 0xffffff;
            timestamp_calc <<= 8;
            ptr = (unsigned __int8 *)&timestamp_calc;
            ptr[ 0 ] = _timestamp;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        timestamp_calc += _timestamp;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
delta = timestamp - previoustimestamp;
if delta > maxtimestamp / 2 {
delta = matimestamp - previoustimestamp + time stamp;}

realtimestamp += delta;
previoustimestamp = timestamp
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Thank you, but it's not quite what I need.